# SwiftUI Onappear Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am rendering Map in SwiftUI, updating the annotations from api response on appear, and I get Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.

Below is the code

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
     @Published var results = [Destination]()
     func getData() {
         // APi call
         self.results = response
     } 
}

struct SampleView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        VStack(spacing: -5) {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: viewModel.categorySearchResults) { dest in
                MapMarker(coordinate: dest.coordinate)
            }
        }.background(Color.clear)
        .onAppear(perform: {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                setRegion(viewModel.getLatLong()!)
                viewModel.getData()
            }
        })
    } else {
    }
}

private func setRegion(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: coordinate,
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
    )
}

}
```

Comment: Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior. this is warning throwing by compiler in the console

Comment: Checkout out this [How to fix “Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior”](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-fix-modifying-state-during-view-update-this-will-cause-undefined-behavior)

Comment: I tried the same, which is not workig

Comment: Are you updating your `results` array data on the main thread?

Comment: Change `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject` and see if it stabilizes things. `@ObservedObject` isn't guaranteed to stay the same when the `View` changes when initialized like this.

Comment: @cedricbahirwe Yes in main thread

Comment: @loremipsum StateObject also giving the same issue

Comment: With the provided code, I'm unable  to reproduce the error, it might be another view causing that error..

Comment: viewModel.getData() fetching the data from api and if I comment             viewModel.getData() on appear the warning is not coming @cedricbahirwe s

Comment: If you just replace the rest of the view body with a dummy `Text`, does the problem still persist?

Comment: Only Map has the issue, I have list which is working fine @Rengers

Comment: In that case I suspect your problem is in some code that was stripped, and is currently not included in the small snippet you posted.

Comment: in `.onAppear` try `DispatchQueue.main.async { viewModel.getData() } `. That will schedule retrieving the data on the next iteration of the run loop after the view first appears instead of during view update.  It should then update again with the new content, but `.onAppear` won't be called again because the view has already appeared.

Comment: @ChipJarred I tried DispatchQueue, which is not working

Comment: @Rengers, Yes you are correct I am updating the Map region also in the onAppear method, you can find the exact code in the Question(Edited) – Rama Krish any thoug

Comment: @Rengers did you get that issue

Comment: I this issue still open? I see you have accepted an answer already.

Comment: @Rengers the warning goes away if we use .constant(region), but that's not correct solution,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this issue because the map is updating on State variable region as well the   @Published property of results, so it is triggering the warning.

replace $region with .constant(region)
Just use the below code that will solve the issue

But if you update the region value, it won't update the Map
or you can send the viewModel.categorySearchResults as a dependency from the previous screen so that you don't need to call the                 viewModel.getData() in the onAppear method

```
  Map(coordinateRegion: .constant(region), showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: viewModel.categorySearchResults) { dest in
                    MapMarker(coordinate: dest.coordinate)
                }
```

Comment: Yes its working, but as you said when I update the region on button tap, its not updating 